# How to mock calls to JQuery without including JQuery in my spec file at all

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, coffeescript, mocking, jasmine

The function I want to test is mostly pure JavaScript (CoffeeScript), but includes one line that calls Jquery:

```
$("input##{name}").change ->
```

I don't want to include Jquery in my Jasmine files at all. I'd like to  mock it out completely so this is a pure unit test.

My spec for this function includes the following:

```
class $
  change: () ->
    return
spy = spyOn($, 'change')
```

However, Jasmine is giving me this error:

```
Error: change() method does not exist
```

How can I mock out `$('input##{name}').change ->` completely in Jasmine without include Jquery in the spec file?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

*Updating here as you can't format comments properly.*

Inspired by the answers below, the contents of my `it` block now looks  like this:

```
  window.$ = (selector) ->
    change: (callback) ->
  spy = spyOn(window.$, "change")
  ...
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9);
```

However, I am getting:

`Error: change() method does not exist`

Comment: Are you using jasmine in the browser or from the command line?

Comment: Both. My functions that don't touch JQuery are specced perfectly, including a function where I `spyOn(history, 'replaceState')`. However, once I try to spec functions that call JQuery by mocking out JQuery it all falls apart.

Comment: If you're doing this in the browser then I recommend using @fracz's answer but put the mock function in an inline script above where all the jasmine stuff is included in the html `window.$ = function() { return { change: function(){} }; };`. Then you can spy it to make sure its called. Not the cleanest solution, but should work and way less ugly than including all of jquery for unit testing.

Comment: Read my answer carefully. **There is no `$.change` method**. You have to spy on the object you are returning, not on the `$`.

Comment: @steven_noble fracz is correct, the $ is a constructor function that returns a jquery object. Remember your other question about coffeescript classes? Same thing here. Its like saying why doesn't my car factory have a steering wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there would be no `$.change` attribute even if you have included jQuery. `$` is a function that returns an object with the `change` attribute. Try:

```
jQuerySelectorMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('jQuerySelectorMock', ['change'])
window.$ = -> jQuerySelectorMock
# test code
expect(jQuerySelectorMock.change).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9)
```

Comment: Thanks but both options just give me a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.

Comment: It depends on how your code uses it. Try assigning to `window.$` instead of just `$`.