# Why can't the functions in my CoffeeScript class 'see' other?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My `foo.coffee` looks like this:

```
class window.Foo
  bar: () ->
    baz()
  baz: () ->
    "baz"
```

In the Google Chrome Console, why then do I get the following?

```
f = new Foo
▶ Foo {}
f.baz
"baz"
f.bar
▶ Uncaught ReferenceError: baz is not defined(…)
```

Comment: have you looked at the output js?

Comment: not sure what that means sorry

Comment: coffeescript *compiles* to javascript. this is always true whether its being done on the fly or upfront. type `coffee -c nameofjsfile` from within that directory to generate the output javascript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how the class abstraction works. Foo is a function with its own scope, so you might think you are defining inner functions that exist in the same scope. But you aren't. This is (more or less) the code that actually gets produced:

```
var Foo = function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return baz();
};
Foo.prototype.baz = function() {
  return "baz";
};
```

So bar only exists on Foo's prototype. Because of the way the `new` operator works in javascript, each instance of Foo gets a pointer to that function. You can reference these prototype functions with `this` which in coffeescript is abbreviated to `@`.

```
class Foo
  bar: () -> 
    @baz()
  baz: () -> 
    'baz'
```

You could alternatively (although it defeats the point of using classes) say:

```
class Foo
  bar: () -> 
    Foo.prototype.baz()
  baz: () -> 
    'baz'
```

Comment: Champion answer. Appreciate the completeness. Perhaps you wouldn't mind also taking a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832310/how-to-mock-calls-to-jquery-without-including-jquery-in-my-spec-file-at-all#37833022

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the @ sign - reference to this/self

```
class window.Foo
  bar: () ->
    @baz()
  baz: () ->
    "baz"
```